# Create dispatch table registering functions across multiple source files in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, dispatch-table

[How can I implement a dynamic dispatch table in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840651/how-can-i-implement-a-dynamic-dispatch-table-in-c/32192330#32192330)

It's essentially the same question as the linked issue, so ...

> As your Strategy.c obviously already knows about the strategy
>   instances by name (`#include "XYstrategy.h"`) you could go the whole
>   mile and use the header files instead of the implementation files to
>   communicate your strategy to the central dispatcher:

This is contrary to the clear intent in the question. This was an example of how he could do it statically, but  wanted to have modules dynamically register themselves at compile time.

Let me try providing an example I'm struggling with for my own purposes...

I have a micro-controller which I want to use to read a variety of sensors that report temperature and/or humidity. I have a central core program which takes care of formatting the returned data and submitting it to a web server where it is recorded in an RRD.

Rather than build a large monolithic program which contains all the different functions for each sensor type, I want to be able to build a specific subset into the software loaded onto the micro-controller which corresponds to the sensors installed on that particular controller.

To do this I would like to be able to write a generic driver for each sensor that has three functions:

```
bool _sensor_startup();
bool _read_sensor(float *temp, float *humidity, uint8_t max_count, uint8_t *count);
bool _sensor_shutdown();
```

The `sensor_startup` function will take care of powering up the sensors, making sure that they are properly configured and in a state of readiness for `read_sensor` to be called. If this process fails for any reason, it returns `false`, otherwise, it returns `true`.

The `read_sensor` function will cause up to `max_count` sensors to be read with their reults stored in the arrays pointed to by `temp` and `humidity`, respectively. The number of sensors read will be stored in `count`.

The `sensor_shutdown` function will do any housekeeping necessary to return the sensors and supporting electronics into their lowest power consumption configuration.

Each of these is contained in a separate .c file which may have a corresponding .h file to define relevant constants, call relevant libraries, etc.

I'd like to have a master Sensor.h file which is included by the .c or .h files and which defines:

```
typedef struct { startup_func, read_func, shutdown_func } sensor_driver_entry;

extern sensor_driver_entry sensor_table[];
```

Then I'd like each Driver file to be able to use a macro (or a function) to register the type-specific functions in the next open slot in sensor_table at compile time.

I'd like sensor table to be declared in the global namespace of Sensor.c as:

```
sensor_driver_entry sensor_table[MAX_SENSOR_TYPES];
```

(`MAX_SENSOR_TYPES` would be defined in Sensor.h reflecting the maximum possible number of drivers that could be selected).

Is this even possible? If so, can someone provide a syntactic example? In this specific case, I'm coding in the Particle Dev environment for a Particle Photon, but I'd like it if I could make the code also portable to the Arduino IDE to use it with ESP8266 boards as well.

Comment: The problem was that you asked a question in the **Answer** section of the other question, rather than posting an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to make use of constructors. Below is a simple example with two drivers registering their functions respectively.

If the application is compiled with both drivers (`gcc main.c driver1.c driver2.c`) the output shows both driver functions registered:

```
driver1_init
driver2_init
driver1_func
driver2_func
```

If only the first driver is compiled in (`gcc main.c driver1.c`) the output shows only that driver's function registered:

```
driver1_init
driver1_func
```

### driver.h

```
typedef void (*driver_func_t)(void);
typedef struct { driver_func_t func; } driver_entry_t;

#define MAX_TYPES 10
extern driver_entry_t driver_table[MAX_TYPES];
extern unsigned int num_driver_entries;
```

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"

driver_entry_t driver_table[MAX_TYPES];
unsigned int num_driver_entries;

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int ix;

    for (ix = 0; ix < num_driver_entries; ix++) {
        driver_table[ix].func();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### driver1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"

void driver1_func (void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

void driver1_init (void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
void driver1_init (void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    driver_table[num_driver_entries++].func = driver1_func;
}
```

### driver2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"

void driver2_func (void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

void driver2_init (void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
void driver2_init (void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    driver_table[num_driver_entries++].func = driver2_func;
}
```