# How to implement a compile-time [dispatch] table for AVR?

Tags: compile-time, avr-gcc

I have the same prerequisites as Dave Durbin in [How can I implement a dynamic dispatch table in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840651/how-can-i-implement-a-dynamic-dispatch-table-in-c/32192330#32192330)... except my target is AVR. Here are my constraints:

- modules are to be picked in a list, much like Linux compiled-in kernel modules
- the number of C (can be C++) modules is known at compile-time
- modules are to be statically linked (obviously)
- I want the table in program memory, [not in SRAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195979/4113344)

Typically, the table should comprise items of this type:

```
typedef struct jump_item {
    uint16_t function_id;
    void (*callback)(void);
} jump_item_t;
```

I have tried using custom sections as suggested in the answer but then the linker throws an error for an unknown symbol `__start_myownsection` (whatever section name I use though). Of course since the code targets Linux/GCC. But I think I'm close because `avr-gcc` actually *can* use [sections](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html), just that I haven't been able to figure out yet how to stack symbols in a user-defined section and actually pointing to the beginning of the table, as well as determine the length of the table at run-time.

How could [Art's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844418/4113344) be adapted to AVR?

---

*** EDIT ***

I can see at least two ways to achieve what I want using sections, either with functions "attached" to a user-defined section or tables of structures (as defined above) that all will stack up in the user-defined section. My current issues are:

- unused variables are optimized away at compile-time!
- unused functions are optimized away at link-time due to linker argument `-gc-sections`, which I need to clean unused functions.

I prefer the second option, something similar to this:

module1.c:

```
const jump_item_t module1_table[] __attribute__((__progmem__, section("tbl_dispatch"))) =
{
    { 0x02, func11 },
    { 0x03, func12 },
    ...
};
```

module2.c:

```
const jump_item_t module2_table[] __attribute__((__progmem__, section("tbl_dispatch"))) =
{
    { 0x12, func21 },
    { 0x13, func22 },
    ...
};
```

Note: indices aren't to be considered relevant.

When all modules define such variables, they're optimized away as there's nowhere any reference to these. They need to stack up in section `tbl_dispatch` though. So my question falls back to:

*How can I tell the compiler from removing variables it "thinks" are unused but only with specific C/C++ modules?*

The global command line I'm using so far is as follows:

```
avr-gcc -g -Wall -mcall-prologues -fshort-enums -Os \
    -DF_CPU=8000000 -Wl,-relax -mmcu=... \
    *.cpp *.c -o main
```

---

*** EDIT ***

To my disappointment, **PROGMEM** and custom sections don't go together. I've tried to combine them but I get disseminated jump tables in program memory... when I get these included at all. Fact is not even all tables appear in program memory.

Giving up.

*Any* idea welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely make a module system if you write your own custom linker script, and copy what was done for constructors and destructors (ctors and dtors).  The linker script below was based on avr5.x from AVR GCC, but I added the dispatch stuff to it.

If you look at the output of the build script in the shell session below, you can see that the dispatch table is set up correctly and has symbols pointing to the start and end of it.  The shell session includes all the source code and build scripts that I used to compile this example.

```
$ ls
avr5-x-modules.ld  build.sh  kernel.c  kernel.h  module_foo.c

$ cat avr5-x-modules.ld
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
/* Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-avr","elf32-avr","elf32-avr")
OUTPUT_ARCH(avr:5)
MEMORY
{
  text   (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 128K
  data   (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x800060, LENGTH = 0xffa0
  eeprom (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x810000, LENGTH = 64K
  fuse      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x820000, LENGTH = 1K
  lock      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x830000, LENGTH = 1K
  signature (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x840000, LENGTH = 1K
  user_signatures (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x850000, LENGTH = 1K
}
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  .hash          : { *(.hash)           }
  .dynsym        : { *(.dynsym)         }
  .dynstr        : { *(.dynstr)         }
  .gnu.version   : { *(.gnu.version)    }
  .gnu.version_d   : { *(.gnu.version_d)        }
  .gnu.version_r   : { *(.gnu.version_r)        }
  .rel.init      : { *(.rel.init)               }
  .rela.init     : { *(.rela.init)      }
  .rel.text      :
    {
      *(.rel.text)
      *(.rel.text.*)
      *(.rel.gnu.linkonce.t*)
    }
  .rela.text     :
    {
      *(.rela.text)
      *(.rela.text.*)
      *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.t*)
    }
  .rel.fini      : { *(.rel.fini)               }
  .rela.fini     : { *(.rela.fini)      }
  .rel.rodata    :
    {
      *(.rel.rodata)
      *(.rel.rodata.*)
      *(.rel.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    }
  .rela.rodata   :
    {
      *(.rela.rodata)
      *(.rela.rodata.*)
      *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    }
  .rel.data      :
    {
      *(.rel.data)
      *(.rel.data.*)
      *(.rel.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    }
  .rela.data     :
    {
      *(.rela.data)
      *(.rela.data.*)
      *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    }
  .rel.ctors     : { *(.rel.ctors)      }
  .rela.ctors    : { *(.rela.ctors)     }
  .rel.dtors     : { *(.rel.dtors)      }
  .rela.dtors    : { *(.rela.dtors)     }
  .rel.got       : { *(.rel.got)                }
  .rela.got      : { *(.rela.got)               }
  .rel.bss       : { *(.rel.bss)                }
  .rela.bss      : { *(.rela.bss)               }
  .rel.plt       : { *(.rel.plt)                }
  .rela.plt      : { *(.rela.plt)               }
  /* Internal text space or external memory.  */
  .text   :
  {
    *(.vectors)
    KEEP(*(.vectors))
    /* For data that needs to reside in the lower 64k of progmem.  */
     *(.progmem.gcc*)
    /* PR 13812: Placing the trampolines here gives a better chance
       that they will be in range of the code that uses them.  */
    . = ALIGN(2);
     __trampolines_start = . ;
    /* The jump trampolines for the 16-bit limited relocs will reside here.  */
    *(.trampolines)
     *(.trampolines*)
     __trampolines_end = . ;
     *(.progmem*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    /* For future tablejump instruction arrays for 3 byte pc devices.
       We don't relax jump/call instructions within these sections.  */
    *(.jumptables)
     *(.jumptables*)
    /* For code that needs to reside in the lower 128k progmem.  */
    *(.lowtext)
     *(.lowtext*)
     __ctors_start = . ;
     *(.ctors)
     __ctors_end = . ;
     __dtors_start = . ;
     *(.dtors)
     __dtors_end = . ;
    KEEP(SORT(*)(.ctors))
    KEEP(SORT(*)(.dtors))
    __dispatch_start = . ;
    *(.dispatch)
    __dispatch_end = . ;
    KEEP(SORT(*)(.dispatch))
    /* From this point on, we don't bother about wether the insns are
       below or above the 16 bits boundary.  */
    *(.init0)  /* Start here after reset.  */
    KEEP (*(.init0))
    *(.init1)
    KEEP (*(.init1))
    *(.init2)  /* Clear __zero_reg__, set up stack pointer.  */
    KEEP (*(.init2))
    *(.init3)
    KEEP (*(.init3))
    *(.init4)  /* Initialize data and BSS.  */
    KEEP (*(.init4))
    *(.init5)
    KEEP (*(.init5))
    *(.init6)  /* C++ constructors.  */
    KEEP (*(.init6))
    *(.init7)
    KEEP (*(.init7))
    *(.init8)
    KEEP (*(.init8))
    *(.init9)  /* Call main().  */
    KEEP (*(.init9))
    *(.text)
    . = ALIGN(2);
     *(.text.*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.fini9)  /* _exit() starts here.  */
    KEEP (*(.fini9))
    *(.fini8)
    KEEP (*(.fini8))
    *(.fini7)
    KEEP (*(.fini7))
    *(.fini6)  /* C++ destructors.  */
    KEEP (*(.fini6))
    *(.fini5)
    KEEP (*(.fini5))
    *(.fini4)
    KEEP (*(.fini4))
    *(.fini3)
    KEEP (*(.fini3))
    *(.fini2)
    KEEP (*(.fini2))
    *(.fini1)
    KEEP (*(.fini1))
    *(.fini0)  /* Infinite loop after program termination.  */
    KEEP (*(.fini0))
     _etext = . ;
  }  > text
  .data          :
  {
     PROVIDE (__data_start = .) ;
    *(.data)
     *(.data*)
    *(.rodata)  /* We need to include .rodata here if gcc is used */
     *(.rodata*) /* with -fdata-sections.  */
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
     _edata = . ;
     PROVIDE (__data_end = .) ;
  }  > data AT> text
  .bss  ADDR(.data) + SIZEOF (.data)   : AT (ADDR (.bss))
  {
     PROVIDE (__bss_start = .) ;
    *(.bss)
     *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
     PROVIDE (__bss_end = .) ;
  }  > data
   __data_load_start = LOADADDR(.data);
   __data_load_end = __data_load_start + SIZEOF(.data);
  /* Global data not cleared after reset.  */
  .noinit  ADDR(.bss) + SIZEOF (.bss)  :  AT (ADDR (.noinit))
  {
     PROVIDE (__noinit_start = .) ;
    *(.noinit*)
     PROVIDE (__noinit_end = .) ;
     _end = . ;
     PROVIDE (__heap_start = .) ;
  }  > data
  .eeprom  :
  {
    /* See .data above...  */
    KEEP(*(.eeprom*))
     __eeprom_end = . ;
  }  > eeprom
  .fuse  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.fuse))
    KEEP(*(.lfuse))
    KEEP(*(.hfuse))
    KEEP(*(.efuse))
  }  > fuse
  .lock  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.lock*))
  }  > lock
  .signature  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.signature*))
  }  > signature
  .user_signatures  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.user_signatures*))
  }  > user_signatures
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab 0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr 0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl 0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr 0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index 0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment 0 : { *(.comment) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
}

$ cat build.sh
CFLAGS="-std=gnu11 -mmcu=atmega328p"
set -uex
avr-gcc $CFLAGS -c module_foo.c -o module_foo.o
avr-gcc $CFLAGS -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
avr-gcc -T avr5-x-modules.ld kernel.o module_foo.o \
        -o program.elf -Wl,-Map=program.map
grep dispatch program.map

$ cat kernel.c
#include "kernel.h"
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

extern dispatch_item * __dispatch_start;
extern dispatch_item * __dispatch_end;

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        for (dispatch_item * item = __dispatch_start; item < __dispatch_end; item++)
        {
            // TODO: Insert code here for reading the contents of the
            // dispatch item from program space and using it.  You
            // probably have to use pgm_read_word avr avr/pgmspace.h,
            // but with GCC 5 you could probably use the new named
            // memory space feature to just access the dispatch item
            // the same way you would access any other struct:
            // https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html
        }
    }
}

$ cat kernel.h
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct dispatch_item {
    uint16_t func_id;
    void (*func)(void);
} dispatch_item;

#define DISPATCH_ITEM dispatch_item const __attribute__((section (".dispatch")))


$ cat module_foo.c
#include "kernel.h"
#include <avr/io.h>

// This gets called before main.
void __attribute__((constructor)) foo_init()
{
    PINB = 0;
}

// There is a pointer to this in the dispatch table.
void foo()
{
    PINB = 1;
}

// DISPATHCH_TABLE_ENTRY(0x12, &foo);

DISPATCH_ITEM foo_dispatch = { 0x12, &foo };

DISPATCH_ITEM foo_dispatch2 = { 0x13, &foo };

$ ./build.sh
++ avr-gcc -std=gnu11 -mmcu=atmega328p -c module_foo.c -o module_foo.o
++ avr-gcc -std=gnu11 -mmcu=atmega328p -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
++ avr-gcc -T avr5-x-modules.ld kernel.o module_foo.o -o program.elf -Wl,-Map=program.map
++ grep dispatch program.map
                0x00000002                __dispatch_start = .
 *(.dispatch)
 .dispatch      0x00000002        0x8 module_foo.o
                0x00000002                foo_dispatch
                0x00000006                foo_dispatch2
                0x0000000a                __dispatch_end = .
 SORT(*)(.dispatch)
```

Comment: Please accept this before the bounty grace period ends!

Comment: Well, it's too late, was busy elsewhere during the week end. I'll study your custom link script and flag your answer when it works for me — never done that before nor know how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the files and build commands I posted in my answer to start off with.

Comment: I haven't really had time nor the opportunity to check it in my application but I'm marking your answer as the solution anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The only practical way I can think of since all my attempts have failed so far is through makefile scripts and menus, much like building Linux Kernel modules: you pick up a series of modules to compile-in and the `make` script generates header/source files with the dispatch table.

The generated source file is built so as to include references to all of the required functions and variables, preventing the garbage collector from ripping them off at link time. I don't have the details of the implementation, this is just a hint that I might follow though not the simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

A custom section will work, but do not use PROGMEM.
With avr-gcc, PROGMEM adds a section attribute.
Adding another will cause problems.
Unless you work at it, the new section will go into program memory.
You do not need to replace the default linker script,
but you need to add to it to get the start and size of the new section.
In the ld manual, see 3.10.9 Builtin Functions ADDR and SIZE,
3.11 Implicit Linker Scripts, 3.5.4 Source Code Reference.